# Make List Items float to left and stack up with no space below them

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to get some li's inside a ul float to the left and stack on eachother.

The format of the ul is

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

This menu is server side generated and cannot be modified.

I've setup a demo to illustrate what i get, and what im after:

What i get:
http://jsfiddle.net/VVyF7/1/

What im after, but without using the positioning as the lis will be dynamically rendered:
http://jsfiddle.net/VVyF7/3/

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand what you want, what you get, what is in your control. Kindly elaborate

Comment: So theres is no structural change that can be done? How about 2 <ul> next to each other? and to clarify.. the starting position of these boxes doesnt matter?

Comment: The answer below solved my issue, works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That layout in the dynamic case can't be done using CSS.

If you can't change the HTML [to have two columns](http://jsfiddle.net/suaaK/11/), you'll have to use JavaScript.

[jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is the best option. There's also [Vanilla Masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/), which is a raw JavaScript version that doesn't rely on jQuery.

Comment: Works absolutely perfect! Exactly what i was looking for! Thanks!